# Checking current location and clicking a link button every few minutes

Tags: html, xpath, location, greasemonkey

Ive got this current situation with an auction site. 
[trada.net](http://www.trada.net) Somtimes they go offline for a few hours, with a current locatoin like: [offline location](http://www.trada.net/errorPage.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/p_home.aspx), now, it basically  disables all my other GM scripts, cause there is no data to analize, and it is the wrong location. Now, how do i ad a piece o script that will check if the current location is the "off line" location, and then if true, click an button on the site named "Live Auctions", with an xpath of :  `.//*[@id='art-main']/div[1]/div[10]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/span[1]/li/a/span[3]`   every 5 minutes, or what ever time frame. The timeframe part i get to execute, but the finding of the link or button still stays a problem, and then also finding my current loaction is my other obstacle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it, assuming the script fires for `http://www.trada.net/*`. :

```
//--- Is this the offline page?
if (/errorPage/i.test (window.location.href) )
{
    //--- Wait 5 minutes and try the main page again.
    var timeDelay       = 5 * 60 * 1000;    //-- 5 min, in milliseconds.

    setTimeout (function() {

        //--- Get "button" target.  Nominally, http://www.trada.net/p_home.aspx
        var desiredPage = $('div#art-main div.art-nav ul.art-menu span li a.active')[0].href;

        window.location.replace (desiredPage);

    }, timeDelay);

    return; //-- Don't process the rest of the script since we are not yet on target page(s).
}
```

Note that you can probably just skip the `desiredPage` part and just use:

```
window.location.replace ('http://www.trada.net/p_home.aspx');
```